# Why do keybindings stop working after pressing the corresponding button?

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

I'm creating a simple Calculator program using Java, Swing.

The keybindings work fine. Well... almost. I ran the software, pressed the number buttons and everything went well, as it should've. Then, I pressed some buttons using my mouse and still, everything is just fine up to this point.

The problem comes when, **after pressing the buttons with my mouse the keybindings stop working**.

Here's the code for pressing the number 0 (the code for the rest of the buttons are implemented in the same way).

```
actions[0] = new press0Action();
frame.getRootPane().getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD0, 0), "0");
frame.getRootPane().getRootPane().getActionMap().put("0", actions[0]);
```

---

```
private class press0Action extends AbstractAction {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            buttons[0].doClick();
        }
    }
```

---

```
private void buttonPressed0() {
        buttons[0].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //Code goes here for pressin the button...
        });
    }
```

---

- **So why can't I use the keyboard after clicking on the buttons in the
  GUI manually with a mouse?**
- **How can I fix this problem?**

Thank you for answering in advance! Feel free to add any suggestions for improvement.

***P.S.:*** I've got a feeling it's something to do with the fact that I bound the keys to `frame.getRootPane()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You registered your inputs for the root pane, and with no explicit condition. Instead try registering them for the entire window:

```
actions[0] = new press0Action();
frame.getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD0, 0), "0");
frame.getRootPane().getRootPane().getActionMap().put("0", actions[0]);
```

Note the alternate getInputMap with argument.